# Syntax highlighting not working for xml/config files in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting appears to be working for all files except xml/config files, which appear completely white.

I have tried deleting .suo files, toying with the XML Formatting options (and whatever else looked interesting in the Options), restarting Visual Studio.

XML formatting is working perfectly - there just is no highlighting.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 2.

Comment: Please check if color settings are correct in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors. In `Display items:` dropdown list, scroll down to XML related items, and check if foreground color is not black.

Comment: That was one of the things I checked when pilfering through the Tools -> Options menu. All of those seem to be set correctly.